# how to configure multiple EMQX exhooks in emqx

Tags: mqtt, emqx

In my deployment, there are 1 EMQX server and 2 GRPC server instances (works as exhooks). How can I configure those two exhooks in EMQX server?
EMQX server version is: 4.4.11, all are running as docker containers

Can I load balance the 2 exhooks via nginx? So then how it can be configured?